# Template reference variable inside component

Tags: angular

I have a component that has some template reference variables declared in its template:

```
<div>
  <input #inp type="text">
  ...more stuff... 
</div>
```

How to access this "#inp" template variable from a main component, like a form?

In my case, I need to set focus to this input when opening the form.

### Update

I use the "app-mycomponent" inside a form "app-myform", like this:

```
<form>
   <app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
   ...other components in this form
</form>
```

In the myform.component.ts I want to focus the "#inp" that is inside "app-mycomponent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply access the template variable via `ViewChild`.

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('inp') // use the name of your template variable
input: ElementRef;
```

Now you can access the input, but it is available in the `ngAfterView` life-cycle hook and later (see [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild))

Update: To set the focus to this element you can execute following:

```
this.input.nativeElement.focus()
```

Update 2: There are multiple ways do this. One way could be to notify your child component via `EventEmitter` or `Subject` to set the focus to your input field. Another way could be to access the child component via `ViewChild` and execute a function, which sets the focus to your input field.

**1. Option:**

myform.component.ts

```
focus$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

...

buttonClickFunction() {
    this.focus$.next();
}
```

myform.component.html

```
<form>
    <app-mycomponent [focus$]="focus$"></app-mycomponent>
    ...other components in this form
</form>
```

app-mycomponent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('inp') // use the name of your template variable
input: ElementRef;

@Input()
focus$: Subject<void>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.focus$.subscribe(() => {
        this.setFocusToInput();
    });
}

setFocusToInput() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

**2. Option:**

myform.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(AppMyComponent) // your component class name
appMyComponent: AppMyComponent

...

// In a function or somewhere else you can call the function to set the focus
buttonClickFunction() {
    this.appMyComponent.setFocusToInput();
}
```

app-mycomponent.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('inp') // use the name of your template variable
input: ElementRef;

...

setFocusToInput() {
    this.input.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

Currently and in your current case i would recommend you the second option.

Comment: Can I do this in the form component?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Sure you can access it from your component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `ViewChild`. Like so:

```
@ViewChild('inp')
input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
```

Read more:
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild